# Unity3D - Calculating t-value position on orbit

Tags: unity-game-engine, math, 3d, geometry, trigonometry

I'm using a script that i found online that uses a kdTree to calculate the nearest point to an object on the surface of a mesh.

I have the following code in the OnDrawGizmos method that allows me to draw a circle that will orbit the surface of the object.

```
x = target.transform.position.x + ((Mathf.Cos(tValue)) * (radius));
z = target.transform.position.z + ((Mathf.Sin(tValue)) * (radius));
Gizmos.color = Color.yellow;
Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(new Vector3(x, y, z), 0.06f);
```

On the the object i am orbiting the "tValue" ranges from 0 to 6.3 to do a full orbit. My problem is that i am trying to calculate the tValue in the range 0-6.3 of an object that is near the central object. I have used my kdTree system to calculate the vector3 position on the surface of the object and it lines up perfectly.

I calculate the radius used in both the above and below equation with:

```
Vector3 RadiusDirection = (Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(orbitingSurfaceMeshPos, planet.transform.up) - Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(planet.transform.position, planet.transform.up));
float radius = RadiusDirection.magnitude;
```

However, when i try to calculate the t-value, i get a completely different value. I figured i could just "reverse" the "equation" and so i've been doing:

```
float temp = orbiting.z - planet.transform.position.z;
temp = temp / radius;
calculatedTvalue = (Mathf.Asin(temp));
```

What could i be doing wrong? I have tested my "reversing equation" in an empty scene and new script and it worked fine, if i just took the result of the orbit position calculation and directly reversed it. However, it doesn't work in my game.

Comment: `ASin` does not cover the entire possible range of angles. Use `calculatedTValue = Mathf.Atan2(RadiusDirection.z, RadiusDirection.x)`.

Comment: You are a legend!!! That worked perfectly.